# Echo: Argument List too long

Tags: shell, arguments, echo, ksh

I'm running into an issue where my argument list for echo is too long and would like some ideas on how to get around this issue, or at least test for the condition so I can properly handle it, and it won't kill my script

```
for file in `cat filelist`; do 
    PROTOCOLS1=`egrep -i 'rsh|rsync|remsh' "$file" | egrep -v '^[ |      ]*#'`
    FIELDS=`echo $PROTOCOLS1|wc -l`
    if [[ $FIELDS -gt 1024 ]]; then
        echo $file >> $debuglog
    else
        set -A myarray $PROTOCOLS1
        do stuff.....
    fi
done
```

So the problem is that when my arg list for echo is too long, `$FIELDS` is set to null, and thus my test for `$FIELDS -gt 1024` always is true and does not get caught.
Problem is when it goes to the array it's obviously too big and I get a subscript out of range error and my script exits.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

---

Edit 9/18

OK so the problem is a little more basic.

```
myserver-v1> echo $variable
myserver-v1> /usr/bin/echo: too many args
```

I want to test for this in my script

I tried the following, which works, but I get all this crap to stdout, which fills up my debug log and is annoying

```
echo $variable
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
write to error log
fi
```

Is there a way to test echo $variable....without sending it to stdout?
I tried the following, but neither seemed to work, so I am kind of at a loss here.

```
[[ ! `echo $variable ]]
[[ `echo $variable ]]
```

Comment: Why not just use `${#myarray[*]}` to get the length of the array (looks like the same as the number of fields) after you set it?  (sorry, I'm less familiar with ksh than bash)

Comment: `$(#myarry[*]}` works in ksh93 (the std on 99% linux systems (that aren't actually pdksh). If `echo ${.sh.version}` returns anything, then you have a ksh93. Good luck to all.

Comment: @evilotto I cannot use `${#myarray[*]}` because that would require that the array already exist....the problem is I cannot create an array over 1024 elements/fields...therefore i must be able to test this prior to running `set -A array `

Comment: The error with too long an argument list is probably a kernel limit, maybe 4k or 8k.  You could just check the raw length of $PROTOCOLS1 with ${#PROTOCOLS} to see it it exceeds some set length determined by trial end error.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the unquoted variable `$PROTOCOLS1` in the `echo`, you could simplify life by replacing:

```
FIELDS=`echo $PROTOCOLS1|wc -l`
```

with

```
FIELDS=1
```

This is because when you echo `$PROTOCOLS1` without any quotes around it, you will only have one (possibly very long) line of output.  Alternatively, you can use:

```
FIELDS=$(echo "$PROTOCOLS1" | wc -l)
```

where the double quotes will preserve the newlines in the value of PROTOCOLS1 (but it gets you back to the 'argument list too long' problem).

So, you need to think about using:

```
FIELDS=$(egrep -i 'rsh|rsync|remsh' "$file" | egrep -c -v '^[ |      ]*#')
```

which gets the second `egrep` to do the line counting for you.  Obviously, since the later portion of the script uses `$PROTOCOLS1`, you will need to re-evaluate the `egreps` to get the data, but you should think about whether your processing scheme is appropriate.  If you are running into a string value that is too long, you are probably not doing the processing in the best way.  What the alternatives are depends on what you are trying to do, and the question does not reveal that.  It might be appropriate to do the extra processing with a scripting language such as Perl, Python or Ruby.