# GNU Parallel: Argument list too long when calling function

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I created a script to verify a (big) number of items and it was doing the verification in a serial way (one after the other) with the end result of the script taking about 9 hours to complete. Looking around about how to improve this, I found *GNU parallel* but I'm having problems making it work.

The list of items is in a text file so I was doing the following:

```
readarray items < ${ALL_ITEMS}
export -f process_item
parallel process_item ::: "${items[@]}"
```

Problem is, I receive an error:

```
GNU parallel: Argument list too long
```

I understand by looking at similar posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120513/gnu-parallel-too-many-input-files-argument-list-too-long), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890632/argument-list-too-long-unix), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414532/echo-argument-list-too-long) that this is more a Linux limitation than a *GNU parallel* one. From the answers to those posts I also tried to extrapolate a workaround by piping the items to *head* but the result is that only a few items (the parameter passed to *head*) are processed.

I have been able to make it work using *xargs*:

```
cat "${ALL_ITEMS}" | xargs -n 1 -P ${THREADS} -I {} bash -c 'process_item "$@"' _ {}
```

but I've seen *GNU parallel* has other nice features I'd like to use.

Any idea how to make this work with *GNU parallel*? By the way, the number of items is about 2.5 million and growing every day (the script run as a cron job).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man parallel`:

```
parallel [options] [command [arguments]] < list_of_arguments
```

So:

```
export -f process_item
parallel process_item < ${ALL_ITEMS}
```

probably does what you want.

Comment: You mean xargs, not parallel:
$ echo a b c | parallel echo
$ _

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the file to parallel, or just use the `-a` (`--arg-file`) option. The following are equvalent:

```
cat "${ALL_ITEMS}" | parallel process_item 
parallel process_item < "${ALL_ITEMS}"
parallel -a "${ALL_ITEMS}" process_item
parallel --arg-file "${ALL_ITEMS}" process_item
parallel process_item :::: "${ALL_ITEMS}"
```

Comment: @OleTange you are right: parallel-20221122-1.fc36.noarch vs. moreutils-parallel-0.67-3.fc36.x86_64